# Ethernet IP camera on Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Wi-Fi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, xorg

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server. I want to connect a PoE (Power-over-Ethernet) IP camera (Amcrest IP8M-T2499EW-40MM) via crossover cable to my Raspberry Pi. I need the Raspberry Pi to connect to the internet via hotspot Wi-Fi.

The software I need to install on the Raspberry Pi 4 will look for the camera and connect to it via IP address. The PoE IP camera is connected to power separately, I just need to figure out how the Raspberry Pi 4 can recognize the camera.

My goal is the Raspberry Pi 4 will be headless and will have software that uses the PoE IP camera to find license plates then sends the data over the Wi-Fo hotspot.

---

Network Layout...

Cellular Hotspot <-(wifi)-> Raspberry Pi <-(ethernet) IP Camera

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-31 22:36 PST
Nmap scan report for _gateway (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.0024s latency).
Nmap scan report for ubuntu (192.168.1.2)
Host is up (0.00064s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.4
Host is up (0.021s latency).
Nmap scan report for ubuntu (192.168.1.21)
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 3.14 seconds
```

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.1.21/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                Verizon:
                    password: ''
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
            optional: false
```

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe66:558  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:66:05:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1268  bytes 106936 (106.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17  bytes 1202 (1.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 30342  bytes 1986060 (1.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 30342  bytes 1986060 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe66:559  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2600:1011:b02d:a13d:dea6:32ff:fe66:559  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether dc:a6:32:66:05:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3176  bytes 432340 (432.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4530  bytes 1673427 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

IP changed on the eth port

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.21.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.21.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe66:558  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:66:05:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1998 (1.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 656 (656.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 433  bytes 30166 (30.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 433  bytes 30166 (30.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe66:559  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2600:1011:b02d:a13d:dea6:32ff:fe66:559  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether dc:a6:32:66:05:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 121  bytes 30262 (30.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 121  bytes 35725 (35.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Are you wanting to view the camera from the rpi?  Meaning, are you sitting at the rpi GUI and trying to access the camera?

Comment: @mikem no, the rpi is headless and will have software that uses the ip camera to find license plates then sends the data over the wifi hotspot.

Comment: ”The power-over-ethernet IP camera is connected to power separately, I just need to figure out how the Raspberry Pi 4 can recognize the camera.” So basically you just want the Raspberry Pi to actually recognize the IP camera and then send the data to some destination? FWIW, you don’t need a crossover cable for Ethernet nowadays. Modern Ethernet connections don’t need crossover cables for direct connections. So you just want to know what IP address the POE IP camera is on?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 essentially. When I start up the unit, i think it's expecting the camera to have internet so it's ignoring my wifi configuration. And if I plug the camera in after boot up, it still isn't recognizing the camera or IP

Comment: @CodyMatthew Well, here is an obvious question: What is the make and model of this PoE IP camera?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Amcrest IP8M-T2499EW-40MM

Comment: How are the camera and rpi getting their IP addresses and routing information?  Can you update your question with a LOT more detail?  Like, exactly how the network is laid out, what routing looks like, how users connect, etc?

Comment: @mikem question updated.  I haven't really done much, I started over from a clean build.  Right now I am mainly just trying to figure out how to config ubuntu to accept a IP camera plugged into its ethernet.

Comment: One problem is that you have the same network assigned to eth0 and wifi... 192.168.1.255.  Change the network on the wifi to something else, ie. 10.1.1.1.  My guess is that the IP camera is defaulting it's IP to the 192.168.1.255 address space.  What IP does the camera have?   How did that IP get assigned to it?

Comment: @mikem i changed the ethernet ip to 192.168.21.21 but it still hasnt made a difference.

Comment: What is the IP address of the camera?  Can you ping it from the rpi?

Comment: @mikem how can I figure that out? The manufacture doesn't say it comes with a static ip by default

Comment: OK, so I suggested that you change the IP address of the wifi, not the ethernet.  See my comment above as to why.  The camera will default to something.  The user manual should tell you.  If not, you can try to nmap that segment (after you fix the addressing) or call the manufacturer and ask them.  My bet is that it's on 192.168.1.x, 192.168.0.x, or somewhere else under 192.x.x.x.  Once you have the IP address, most cameras have a web-based admin interface that you connect to with your browser.  Whatever they tell you the address is, make sure your eth0 network is the same as on the camera.

Comment: @mikem so should i turn dhcp4 back on for ethernet and remove the IP address assignment? Then change the fixed ip assignment on the wifi ?

Comment: We really need to know how the camera is getting it's address.  Most come with a static IP address.  Some will come with DHCP enabled by default.  Most cameras come with Windows software to help set them up.  You might get along easier if you tried to set it up using the windows utilities that come with the camera so you can figure out the addressing.  Then, connect it back to the rpi.  If the camera didn't come with any software or instructions, check the manufactures web site.  We really need to know what the camera is doing.  Once you have that, we can figure out the rest of the networking.

Comment: @mikem so i hooked the cam up to my network and set it up with a static IP of 192.168.1.200  but when i plugged it back into the rpi, i cant access it still.

Comment: did you set the eth0 address back to 192.168.1.21 on your rpi?  can you ping it from the rpi?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117932/discussion-between-cody-matthew-and-mikem).